# OpenVAS Go TLS Certificate Error

Tags: ssl, go, tls1.2, gnutls, openvas

I'm currently developing a custom scanner in go for OpenVAS. Problem is that the handshake with my custom server fails.

I traced the problem down to error `-73`: `GNUTLS_E_ASN1_TAG_ERROR` from `gnutls_handshake`, but I can't find any resources on that problem. I read something about the certificates being incorrect then but I can't do anything other than regenerating the OpenVAS certificates. The tls functionality in the go server just uses a simple `ListenAndServeTLS` and gets the server cert and key.

edit:
So this is the relevant network part on the custom scanner:

```
var (
    port = ":1234"
    cert = "/usr/local/var/lib/openvas/CA/servercert.pem"
    ca   = "/usr/local/var/lib/openvas/CA/cacert.pem"
    key  = "/usr/local/var/lib/openvas/private/CA/serverkey.pem"
)

    func start_server() {

    ca_file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(ca)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    blocks, _ := pem.Decode( ca_file )
    ca, err := x509.ParseCertificate(blocks.Bytes)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    priv_file, _ := ioutil.ReadFile(key)
    blocks2, _ := pem.Decode( priv_file )

    priv, err := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(blocks2.Bytes)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    pool := x509.NewCertPool()
    pool.AddCert(ca)

    cert := tls.Certificate{
        Certificate: [][]byte{ca_file},
        PrivateKey:  priv,
    }

    config := tls.Config{
        ClientAuth:   tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
        ClientCAs:    pool,
    }
    config.Rand = rand.Reader
    service := "0.0.0.0" + port
    listener, err := tls.Listen("tcp", service, &config)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server: listen: %s", err)
    }
    log.Print("server: listening")

    for {
        conn, err := listener.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Printf("server: accept: %s", err)
            break
        }

        defer conn.Close()
        log.Printf("server: accepted from %s", conn.RemoteAddr())
        go handle(conn)
    }
}
```

func handle(conn net.Conn) {

```
str := "Hello"

defer conn.Close()

buf := make([]byte, 512)
for {
    log.Print("server: conn: waiting")
    conn.Write( ([]byte)(str) )
    n, err := conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println (err)
        }
        break
    }

    tlscon, ok := conn.(*tls.Conn)
    if ok {
        state := tlscon.ConnectionState()
        sub := state.PeerCertificates[0].Subject
        log.Println(sub)
    }

    log.Printf("server: conn: echo %q\n", string(buf[:n]))
    n, err = conn.Write(buf[:n])

    n, err = conn.Write(buf[:n])
    log.Printf("server: conn: wrote %d bytes", n)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("server: write: %s", err)
        break
    }
}
log.Println("server: conn: closed")
```

}

func main() {

```
start_server()
```

}

It's taken from an example but it didn't work properly at first ( there was no decode before parsecertificates). Maybe the certificate is mal-formatted now because of that? Before adding the two decodes I had a similar error about the asn1 tags not matching. So also an asn1 error. I thought of generating my own certificate but I don't know if this will not break OpenVAS for the other scanners. I had the same results when just using listenandservetls from go. The error is definitely produced in gnutls_handshake. It's frustrating that I only get an error code from that.

Comment: Please consider adding some sample code of what you're doing instead of just describing it. Often times mistakes lie in subtle implementation problems which are much easier to troubleshoot if you post your code.

Comment: Please provide a URL for the server, and some code to go with it. GnuTLS's ASN.1 parser is very strict. I seem to recall a way to make it relax during parsing, but it escapes me at the moment. You might be able to find the reference to the problem and solution; or maybe switch to another library.